# CentOS Installation

Tags: sd-card, software-installation, hard-drive

Sandisk 128gb micro SD. plugged into usb converter.

Initial fdisk format: Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type /dev/sdf1 * 2048 249737215 249735168 119.1G c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Format with parted to fat32.

All looks good.

Then run etcher with image: CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-RaspberryPI-Minimal-4-2003-sda.raw on device /dev/sdf

outcome:

```
lsblk: sdf 8:80 1 119.1G 0 disk
├─sdf1 8:81 1 286M 0 part
├─sdf2 8:82 1 488M 0 part
└─sdf3 8:83 1 1.7G 0 part
```

sdf3 being /

`dd if=image of=/dev/sdf` also same outcome.

This is completely and utterly useless.

What the heck is going on here? I must have some fundamental misunderstanding of something. but I am not able to pin it down.

I want my root part to contain the remaining bytes of the disk.

To my knowledge Raspberry Pi's don't like LVM or really anything except fat. So resizing is not doable? Also, to my understanding I can't just take a live USB shove it in a Raspberry Pi, expect to be able to boot into it, then do all the work manually on install. So I am kind of at the end of my working knowledge...

Sigh. Please help me understand.

Comment: "Please help me understand." It might help is you explained your problem and what you did. Also link to whatever you are using, properly edit the post. It wouldn't hurt if you checked your spelling.

Comment: @Milliways "It might help if* you explained your problem and what you did."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't ever used CentOS but here are some general issues as far as I understand your question.

You partition your SD Card with `fdisk` and it seems you expect that the image fit into the created partition. But an image is a raw copy bit by bit from a source installation containing also its partitioning and formatting. If you restore it e.g. with `etcher` or `dd` you have an exact copy of the source installation. This is why it shows you the original partitioning with three partitions `sdf[1..3]`. Your partitioning with `fdisk` is just overwritten.

That means you have to live with the given partitions of the installation if you do not want to create your own installation from scratch. Of course, after flashing the image you are able to resize the given partitions to your needs. You will find many examples on this site how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to further clarify, there's a step-by-step [here](https://medium.com/@petermcd/installing-centos-on-a-raspberry-pi-2112e9ee68fc) (*Installing CentOS on a Raspberry Pi*). Does that match what you've done exactly, approximately or just in general?

I haven't tried CentOS on any of my Raspberry Pi computers, but using the Raspberry Pi imager, I've got cards up to 1 TB running Raspbian on the 3b, 3b+ and 4 families.

I realize you state that you want all your storage to be in the one partition, but UNIX/Linux is less fussy about multiple partitions than, say, Windows. You can create a new volume in the vacant 117 GB and mount that under a (currently empty) subdirectory on your / volume. Sorry I can't provide details but it's been a long time since I last had to mess with UNIX and mounting volumes (SVR3, actually, back in the last century).

You might try installing Raspbian, which can handle large drives from the install, then use a USB device with a CentOS installer to kick off the new install.

There's also [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/LinuxNotes/comments/efcj0c/centos7_raspberry_pi_4_install/) (*CentOS-7 | Raspberry Pi 4 Install*), which talks about rootfs -expand, which might just be what you need. It also may be usable in changing from a Raspbian install to a CentOS machine.